# ¿Por qué sale ese resultado en mi terminal al ejecutar este código?

Tags: java

Éste es un código que resuelve la fórmula cuadrática, al ejecutar en blueJ me funcionó.
Según el compilador no hay errores, pero hoy salió este resultado en la terminal:

```
Escriba el coeficiente de x^2
4
Escriba el coeficiente de x
8
Escriba el termino independiente
9
```

Las soluciones son:

> **x1=NaNy x2= NaN**

```
import java.util.*;
  public class FormulaCuadratica
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
    { Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Escriba el coeficiente de x^2");
        double a= in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Escriba el coeficiente de x");
        double b= in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Escriba el termino independiente");
        double c= in.nextDouble();
        double x1= (-b+(Math.sqrt(b*b-4*(a*c))))/(2*a);
        double x2= (-b-(Math.sqrt(b*b-4*(a*c))))/(2*a);
        System.out.println("Las soluciones son: x1=" + x1 + "y x2= " + x2);
```

Comment: `NaN` suele significar "not a number". Yo me fijaría en el cálculo del discriminante para ver si se está sacando la raíz cuadrada a números negativos.

Comment: Efectivamente las soluciones de una cuadrática pueden ser reales o complejas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que mencionas se debe a que las soluciones para esa ecuación tienen un número imaginario, que se obtiene al querer obtener la raíz de un número negativo.

La soluciones a esa ecuación son:

```
 x1≈-1.0000 + 1.1180 i  
x2≈-1.0000 - 1.1180 i
```

Java no puede representar el número imaginario.

Si quieres mostrar esa solución puedes usar este código que adapté en base al tuyo.

```
public static void main(String[]args){ 
   Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Escriba el coeficiente de x^2");
    double a= in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Escriba el coeficiente de x");
    double b= in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Escriba el termino independiente");
    double c= in.nextDouble();
    double val = b*b-4*(a*c);
    if (val > 0) {
        double x1= (-b+(Math.sqrt(val)))/(2*a);
        double x2= (-b-(Math.sqrt(val)))/(2*a);
        System.out.println("Las soluciones son: x1=" + x1 + "y x2= " + x2); 
    } else {
        System.out.println("Las soluciones son: x1=" + (-b)/(2*a) +"+"+ Math.sqrt(val*-1) / (2*a) + "i");
        System.out.println("Las soluciones son: x1=" + (-b)/(2*a) +"-"+ Math.sqrt(val*-1) / (2*a) +"i");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

NaN es el acrónimo de *Not a Number* (No es un número)

Cuando trabajas con números con coma flotante, se suele seguir [la norma IEEE 754](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#NaN_en_coma_flotante), que especifica que cuando el resultado de una operación aritmética es indefinido (la raíz de -1, o 0 dividido por 0, por ejemplo), pasa a ser NaN:

> Los siguientes casos pueden generar el estado de NaN en la mayoría de
>   los lenguajes de programación que acepten este estado como retorno de
>   una función matemática:
>
> - Todas las operaciones matemáticas que posean NaN como operando matemático.
> - Las divisiones indeterminadas o por infinito (0/0, ∞/∞, ∞/-∞, -∞/∞)
> - Las multiplicaciones de 0 por infinito (0×∞, 0×-∞)
> - Las restas de valores infinitos (∞ -∞)
> - Aplicando funciones que excedan el dominio de la misma. Por ejemplo, la raíz cuadrada de un número negativo, logaritmo de cualquier número
>     menor o igual que 0, o la inversa de un coseno que sea menor que -1 o
>     mayor que +1.

Comment: La parte en la que dices *demasiado grande* o *demasiado pequeño* me causa ruido. No creo que sea correcto, puesto que `+infito` y `-infinito` son valores especiales en punto flotante, al igual que `+0` y `-0`